# Resizing Windows Top Most Window in C#

Tags: c#, window, window-resize

I would like to resize the topmost windows. I have small problem in the code below. It doesnt resize the window smaller or to bigger size if the window is not maximized when the program starts. Do you have any idea to fix it?

CODE:

```
      int handle = 0;
      handle = GetForegroundWindow();

      System.Drawing.Rectangle r = new System.Drawing.Rectangle();
      GetWindowRect(handle, ref r);


      if (jointLeft.Position.X < jointRight.Position.X - 0.15 && jointLeft.Position.X >jointRight.Position.X - 0.30)
      {
      Debug.WriteLine("smaller (" + r.Left + ";" + r.Top + ")" + (r.Right - r.Left - 10) + "x" + (r.Bottom - r.Top));
      SetWindowPos(handle, -1, r.Left, r.Top, (r.Right - r.Left) - 10,r.Bottom - r.Top + 8, SHOWWINDOW);

      } else if (jointLeft.Position.X < jointRight.Position.X - 0.30 && jointLeft.Position.X > jointRight.Position.X - 0.50)
      {
      Debug.WriteLine("bigger (" + r.Left + ";" + r.Top + ")" + (r.Right - r.Left + 10) + "x" + (r.Bottom - r.Top) );
      SetWindowPos(handle, -1,r.Left, r.Top, (r.Right - r.Left) + 18, r.Bottom - r.Top + 8, SHOWWINDOW);
      }
```

Comment: GetWindowRect() returns a RECT, not a Rectangle.  A handle is an IntPtr, not an int.  Visit pinvoke.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done top-most window resizing with "Media Player Classic - Home Cinema" application (process name is "mpc-hc"). It works for me.

Please try the following code.

Native definitions:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool GetWindowRect(HandleRef hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
    public int Left;        // x position of upper-left corner
    public int Top;         // y position of upper-left corner
    public int Right;       // x position of lower-right corner
    public int Bottom;      // y position of lower-right corner
}

/// <summary>
/// Special window handles.
/// </summary>
public enum SpecialWindowHandles
{
    // ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
    /// <summary>
    ///     Places the window at the bottom of the Z order. If the hWnd parameter identifies a topmost window, the window loses its topmost status and is placed at the bottom of all other windows.
    /// </summary>
    HWND_TOP = 0,
    /// <summary>
    ///     Places the window above all non-topmost windows (that is, behind all topmost windows). This flag has no effect if the window is already a non-topmost window.
    /// </summary>
    HWND_BOTTOM = 1,
    /// <summary>
    ///     Places the window at the top of the Z order.
    /// </summary>
    HWND_TOPMOST = -1,
    /// <summary>
    ///     Places the window above all non-topmost windows. The window maintains its topmost position even when it is deactivated.
    /// </summary>
    HWND_NOTOPMOST = -2
    // ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming
}

[Flags]
public enum SetWindowPosFlags : uint
{
    // ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming

    /// <summary>
    ///     If the calling thread and the thread that owns the window are attached to different input queues, the system posts the request to the thread that owns the window. This prevents the calling thread from blocking its execution while other threads process the request.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_ASYNCWINDOWPOS = 0x4000,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Prevents generation of the WM_SYNCPAINT message.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_DEFERERASE = 0x2000,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Draws a frame (defined in the window's class description) around the window.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_DRAWFRAME = 0x0020,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Applies new frame styles set using the SetWindowLong function. Sends a WM_NCCALCSIZE message to the window, even if the window's size is not being changed. If this flag is not specified, WM_NCCALCSIZE is sent only when the window's size is being changed.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_FRAMECHANGED = 0x0020,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Hides the window.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_HIDEWINDOW = 0x0080,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Does not activate the window. If this flag is not set, the window is activated and moved to the top of either the topmost or non-topmost group (depending on the setting of the hWndInsertAfter parameter).
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOACTIVATE = 0x0010,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Discards the entire contents of the client area. If this flag is not specified, the valid contents of the client area are saved and copied back into the client area after the window is sized or repositioned.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOCOPYBITS = 0x0100,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Retains the current position (ignores X and Y parameters).
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOMOVE = 0x0002,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Does not change the owner window's position in the Z order.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOOWNERZORDER = 0x0200,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Does not redraw changes. If this flag is set, no repainting of any kind occurs. This applies to the client area, the nonclient area (including the title bar and scroll bars), and any part of the parent window uncovered as a result of the window being moved. When this flag is set, the application must explicitly invalidate or redraw any parts of the window and parent window that need redrawing.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOREDRAW = 0x0008,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Same as the SWP_NOOWNERZORDER flag.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOREPOSITION = 0x0200,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Prevents the window from receiving the WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING message.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOSENDCHANGING = 0x0400,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Retains the current size (ignores the cx and cy parameters).
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOSIZE = 0x0001,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Retains the current Z order (ignores the hWndInsertAfter parameter).
    /// </summary>
    SWP_NOZORDER = 0x0004,

    /// <summary>
    ///     Displays the window.
    /// </summary>
    SWP_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0040,

    // ReSharper restore InconsistentNaming
}

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, SetWindowPosFlags uFlags);
```

The Main of the Program:

```
Process[] processesByName = Process.GetProcessesByName("mpc-hc");
Process process = processesByName.FirstOrDefault();
if (process == null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Process not found");
    return;
}
IntPtr windowHandle = process.MainWindowHandle;

RECT r;
GetWindowRect(new HandleRef(this, windowHandle), out r);

int cx = r.Right - r.Left;
int cy = r.Bottom - r.Top;

cx -= 20;
cy -= 20;

SetWindowPos(windowHandle, (IntPtr) SpecialWindowHandles.HWND_TOPMOST, r.Left, r.Top, cx, cy, SetWindowPosFlags.SWP_SHOWWINDOW);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, but what if I want to resize any window, not specified by name like you did ("mpc-hc"), but one that is top most ?

Comment: @Samet, mpc-hc (Media Player Classic) application has an option (always top-most), I've used Media Player Classic window just for the example. So, ignore this part of code. You just need to get a window handle of **desired** window: [foreground window](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getforegroundwindow).

Comment: Thank you Serge, I will try... If I can't, I will get your opinion again if possible.